# Adding sum row to specific columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'project': 123456, 'date': '08/07/2019', 'total': 123, 
                    'count': 12}, {'project': 123457, 'date': '08/07/2019', 
                    'total': 124, 'count': 13}, {'project': 123458, 'date': 
                    '08/07/2019', 'total': 125, 'count': 14}])
```

I'd like to add a total row to the bottom of only the `total` and `count` columns. I know I can do

```
df.loc['Total'] = df.sum(numeric_only=True)
```

But my `project` column is numeric and I do *not* want the word `Total` at the bottom row, only the sums for those two columns. Is there any way to remove the word and ensure that only those two columns get summed?

Comment: Not sure what you want, but to avoid the word total, just do `df.loc[len(df)] = df.sum(numeric_only=True)`

Comment: @rafaelc how can I avoid my `project` column getting summed? Since it's numeric as well.

Comment: slice yours columns `df[cols_to_add].sum()` where `cols_to_add = ['col1', 'col2', ...] etc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for something like this

```py
In [1]:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'project': 123456, 'date': '08/07/2019', 'total': 123, 
                    'count': 12}, {'project': 123457, 'date': '08/07/2019', 
                    'total': 124, 'count': 13}, {'project': 123458, 'date': 
                    '08/07/2019', 'total': 125, 'count': 14}])

df.append(df[['count', 'total']].sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)

Out [1]:
    count   date         project    total
0   12.0    08/07/2019   123456.0   123.0
1   13.0    08/07/2019   123457.0   124.0
2   14.0    08/07/2019   123458.0   125.0
3   39.0    NaN          NaN        372.0
```

Comment: [Deprecated since pandas version 1.4.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

Answer (score 8):

I believe each project has a unique ID, so I don't know if this will be a valid solution. Since there are no limitations to the question, I propose the following, by using the column project as an index, you can easily add further project id's with their information, and the final row will sum them all up!

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'project': 123456, 'date': '08/07/2019', 'total': 123, 
                    'count': 12}, {'project': 123457, 'date': '08/07/2019', 
                    'total': 124, 'count': 13}, {'project': 123458, 'date': 
                    '08/07/2019', 'total': 125, 'count': 14}])
df1 = df.set_index('project')
df1.loc['Total'] = df1.sum(numeric_only=True)
print(df1)
```

And I get this result, which is what I believe you want:

```
               date  total  count
project
123456   08/07/2019  123.0   12.0
123457   08/07/2019  124.0   13.0
123458   08/07/2019  125.0   14.0
Total           NaN  372.0   39.0
```

Comment: That's twice today I've deleted an answer of mine because I liked another answer so much more.

Comment: Excuse me, I'm not sure I understood the point of the reply (no sarcasm meant, just 0 skills when it comes to communication and emotional intelligence).

Comment: I'm saying that this is a very good answer.  So good that I decided to delete my answer because I want the OP to focus on this one.  **AND** it happens to be the second time I've done that today (-:

Answer (score 0):

I would had done it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([{'project': 123456, 'date': '08/07/2019', 'total': 123, 
                    'count': 12}, {'project': 123457, 'date': '08/07/2019', 
                    'total': 124, 'count': 13}, {'project': 123458, 'date': 
                    '08/07/2019', 'total': 125, 'count': 14}])

# Append an empty row at the bottom of the df
df.loc[df.shape[0]] = [np.nan for col_num in range(1,df.shape[1]+1)]

# Write the sums of the columns you want at the last row 
df.iloc[df.shape[0]-1,[2,3]] = df.iloc[:,[2,3]].sum(axis=0)
```

Output:

```
     project          date  total   count
0   123456.0    08/07/2019  123.0   12.0
1   123457.0    08/07/2019  124.0   13.0
2   123458.0    08/07/2019  125.0   14.0
3        NaN           NaN  372.0   39.0
```

This way you can calculate the sums of any columns you want and append them at the last row, no matter how many rows or columns your df has.