# add total row count in dataframe without impacting column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My data is as below

| Sec | issues | Gaps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 22 | 5 |
| BBB | 33 | 2 |
| CCC | 44 | 1 |

Desired result

| Sec | issues | Gaps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 22 | 5 |
| BBB | 33 | 2 |
| CCC | 44 | 1 |
| TOTAL | 99 | 8 |

I try below code

`df.append(df.sum(numeric_only=True), ignore_index=True)`

but with this I miss sector name and simply get totals at end, I want sector name and totals both

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your use case for this? It's strange to me that you explicitly want to mix summary data in your DataFrame itself.

Comment: Try `df.loc[len(df)]=['Total', *df.iloc[:,1:].sum()]` ([related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76132725/19123103))

Comment: Please include your `pd.__version__` in the body of your question. If you use `df.append`, which is [deprecated since version 1.4.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html), then answers will have to fit your version. Alternatively, update and use [Good alternative to Pandas .append() method, now that it is being deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70837397/12846804)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding sum row to specific columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401674/adding-sum-row-to-specific-columns-in-dataframe). I was going to suggest exactly that. Set as index the 'Sec' column, then create new row with df.sum(), finally reset the index (with drop=False)

Answer (score 1):

Build a new dataframe with additional row (retaining the initial columns):

```
(pd.DataFrame([*df.values, ['Total', *df.sum(numeric_only=True).values]], 
              columns=df.columns))
```

---

```
     Sec  issues  Gaps
0   AAA       22     5
1   BBB       33     2
2   CCC       44     1
3  Total      99     8
```

Comment: Cool, upvoted. By the way, this actually works only when the non numeric column is not *in between* the numeric ones, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked -- df.loc["Total"] = df.sum()

Comment: Not quite. The point is to avoid applying the sum to the column of dtype object. You have use OP exact input and show your exact output.

Answer (score 0):

**About your attempt:**

- What is your `pd.__version__`? `df.append` is [deprecated since version 1.4.0](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html). Our answers will not necessarily fit your version. Here is mine: `2.0.3`
- The next issue is `.sum(numeric_only=True)` not having the correct size for insertion, because a non numeric column will be **skipped**, not written in, as None for example *(wish it was)*.

---

**Alternatively:**

Temporarily hiding non numeric columns into the index looks like the simplest alternative and does not suffer from deprecation: (based on [Adding sum row to specific columns in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57401674/adding-sum-row-to-specific-columns-in-dataframe))

```py
df.set_index(  keys='Sec', inplace=True) # Send object column to index
df.loc['TOTAL'] = df.sum()               # Add sum row
df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True) # Restore index
```

Output:

```py
     Sec  issues  Gaps
0    AAA      22     5
1    BBB      33     2
2    CCC      44     1
3  TOTAL      99     8
```

A note:

- This method avoids the risk of mixing up sums that might arise with other methods involving *reconstructing* another dataframe.
- Slightly outside the scope of your question, this can be adapted to the case where df were to have several non numeric columns scattered in between numeric columns.